# Is it Possible to Create Concurrent Threads using One Function In Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to threading and sorry if this question is very naive, but I cannot seem to find an exact answer for it. So, let's I want to create a program which iterates through the numbers between 0-99. Each number is sent to a function which prints it counting up by one until its a hundred more than the original number passed in. Lets then say I want to make each call of this function run concurrently. I.e I pass in 0 and it starts counting, and while 0 is counting 1 is passed in and it starts counting, and then 2 is passed in and starts counting etc. until 99. So all these numbers are counting simultaneously up before the previous is finished. I was wondering how it would be possible to do this. I originally tried to do with the code on the bottom, but it seems like it is just creating a single thread and then staying in the function until its finished before going to the next number.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out if its possible to dynamically create new threads using a singular function. If its possible to exit the startCount function meanwhile a thread in it is running, then call it again to create another thread to run beside the old one. Thank you for any help.

edit: I'm dumb. Thank you for helping me.

```
def countUp100(num):
    end = num+100
    while(num!=end):
        num = num + 1
        print(num)     
    print("finished")

def startCount(num):
    thread = threading.Thread(target = countUp100(num))
    thread.start

def main():
    for i in range(100):
        startCount(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added my modified code;

```
import threading

def countUp100(num):
    end = num + 100
    while (num != end):
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
    print("finished")


def startCount(num):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=countUp100, args=(num,))
    thread.start()

def main():
    for i in range(100):
        startCount(i)

main()
```

I'd be very happy if you let me know the result. Best Regards

Comment: It's my pleasure. If you have any questions or problems, please let me know.